# Collect and echo submission via multiple <select> tags in submission form?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

My basic goal is to "capture" three values from three  menus (Year, month, day), and print them on the next page pointed to by the submission form. I've been trying all day to find a way to do such - No luck whatsoever, I can only manage to print one of the three values.

An abbreviated version of my select menus:

```
<form action="processform.php" method="POST">
<select name="birthdate_year[ ]">
 <option value="2003">2003</option>
 <option value="2004">2004</option>
 <option value="2005">2005</option>
</select>

<select name="birthdate_month[ ]">
 <option value="01">January</option>
 <option value="02">Feburary</option>
 <option value="03">March</option>
</select>

<select name="birthdate_day[ ]">
 <option value="01">01</option>
 <option value="02">02</option>
 <option value="03">03</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

...And the following shows how I've managed to only get one value to become an array:

```
 foreach( $_POST['birthdate_year'] as $year ) /*Neither &&/|| work, and I cannot "add" to it or add another "foreach" */
     {
       print $year;
     }
```

I've been scouring the internet for a way to do such - The only working method is "foreach", which can only seemingly convert one value to an array (It won't accept "AND" statements, or for that matter, another "foreach").

All I want is to have each entered value become it's own array - All of whom need to be accessed multiple times to complete the program's function (Compute if whether the user is above/below a cutoff age & storing their birthdate for later examination when they become old enough)

Programs for storing their age and determining their age "group" have already been written - Now I just need each value to become it's own array.

**Solution found**

For some reason it wouldn't accept multiple "foreach" statements if they weren't descending in some weird way - So now that they're doing so, it works.

Comment: Do you have javascript that goes with this?

Comment: No, it's all PHP. Just a simple submit form. The page the submission takes place on is separate from the page where the program runs - The submission form points towards the page with the program.

Comment: So how are you passing data from your form?

Comment: The thing is I've tried quite a few methods - Nothing's definite as far as making all three values become arrays. Would you like to see how I managed to get only one to work?

Comment: "Would you like to see how I managed to get only one to work? " Yes

Comment: Sorry that took that long, I've added it to the main question.

Comment: This isn't a forum - we don't edit titles as `(RESOLVED)`. Instead, we *accept* an answer. If you found the correct solution, you should write the answer yourself, and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is:
    
    
     2003
     2004
     2005

```
<select name="birthdate[month]">
 <option value="01">January</option>
 <option value="02">Feburary</option>
 <option value="03">March</option>
</select>

<select name="birthdate[day]">
 <option value="01">01</option>
 <option value="02">02</option>
 <option value="03">03</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Notice that the indexes have no quotes. As you do it, you have to check the following variables:

```
$_POST['birthdate_month'][0]
$_POST['birthdate_day'][0]
$_POST['birthdate_year'][0]
```

which is not so nice.